# mpi file read is not ending

Tags: c, file-io, mpi

I am trying to read a txt file using mpi in the following way:

"The master node should load the data, divide and distribute it among the
worker processors."

However my code is not ending.

Here is the corresponding code piece:

```
MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);

if (rank == 0){

    printf("OK\n");   

    MPI_Offset filesize;
    MPI_Offset localsize;
    MPI_Offset start;
    MPI_Offset end;
    char *chunk;

    MPI_File_get_size(in, &filesize);
//localsize = filesize/size;
    start = 0;
    end   = filesize - 1;
    printf("OK\n");

localsize =  end - start + 1;

/* allocate memory */
    chunk = malloc( (localsize + 1)*sizeof(char));

    MPI_File_read_at_all(in, start, chunk, localsize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("OK\n");
    chunk[localsize] = '\0';
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

The code above doesnt print the third "OK". Therefore the problem is in `MPI_File_read_at_all()`, I guess.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason for using MPI IO instead of regular IO (from, say, `<stdio.h>`) when all you're doing is reading from a *single* node?  From what I read, MPI IO is for *parallel, collective IO*, so this kind of defeats the purpose (and might explain why it's stuck).

Comment: I think you are right but this is a school project. May be it is TA's mistake. Anyway I just need to learn how to read file and send/receive messages between processors.

Comment: @Rufflewind, MPI IO is perfectly usable in non-parallel cases and even comes handy, e.g. it allows transferring data using derived MPI datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_File_read_at_all` is a **collective** version of `MPI_File_read_at`. Collective operations only complete once all ranks in the given communicator have made the call. In your case the open operation encompasses `MPI_COMM_WORLD` while you only call `MPI_File_read_at_all` in rank 0.

You should replace it with the non-collective `MPI_File_read_at` or, even better, use the standard C I/O routines instead.